# Remove Active Directory on a Terminal-License Server with windows 2003

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, terminal-server

does anyone know, when i remove the AD/DC Role from a Windows Terminal-Server what is also a Terminal-License Server, will there are any serious issues? Or can i remove AD Roles with dcpromo easily (we have two other DC's on the Network).

Or what would you do, so that this server is only Terminal-License Server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so far i removed the Terminal-Server Role without any problems, so it is only Directory and Terminal-License-Server.

After i got rid of the License-Server (moved to another one) i could depromote the AD Server to a normal one and put him out of the net.

No Problems so far, Thanks!